# following tutorial for rust & diesel getting stuck with diesel::Queryable not satisfied

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

learning rust with a simple rest api....
I am following https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html
until trying to insert stuff all went well...

in `models.rs` I have:

```
#[derive(Queryable, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Deftables {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
}
#[derive(Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = deftables)]
pub struct Newtable<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
}
```

now I try:

```
#[post("/setup")] // <- define path parameters
async fn setups(data: web::Data<helpers::AppState>) -> impl Responder {
    use crate::schema::deftables;
    use crate::schema::deftables::dsl::*;
    println!("setup ");
    let con = &mut data.db.get().unwrap();
    println!("connected");
    let target = deftables
        .load::<Deftables>(con)
        .expect("Error loading tables");
    println!("Tables are {:#?}", target);
    if target.len() <= 0 {
        let tbldata = vec!["deftables", "user", "acl"];
        for nwt in &tbldata {
            let filltable = Newtable { name: nwt };
            let msg = "Error saving new entry ".to_owned() + nwt;
            diesel::insert_into(deftables::table)
                .values(&filltable)
                .get_result(con)
                .expect(&msg)
        }
        HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Setup proceeding "))
    } else {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Setup failed, deftables not empty {:#?} ", target))
    }
}
```

I copied over the insert_into part from the tutorial and just adapted to my case, but this fails on the line  `.get_result(con)` with

```
     error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): diesel::Queryable<(Integer,  diesel::sql_types::Text), Pg>` is not satisfied
     --> src/users/routes.rs:81:29
      |
81    |                 .get_result(con)
                         ---------- ^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<(Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text), Pg>` is not implemented for `()`
      |                  |
      |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
```

now I have my problems with the sample of the tutorial anyway, it tells that the resulting id is set for the resulting query, but, as in my case, I have 2 structs for the same thing, Deftable and Newtable, Newtable missing the id field, but the queriable thing is Deftable, not Newtable i try to create, is there a way to bypass Newtable struct completely, the idea of doubling the code just because of the conflicting (set by default by the DB) id field seems akward? Still remains the problem, where lands the newly created id??

And what do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_result()` method relays on type inference for the return type of the query if that's not explicitly specified. This is the case for the example from the getting started guide. There the type is specified as return type of the function, as the relevant call of `get_result()` is basically the last call in that function.

Your example is different. You execute the query inside of a loop. Loops are inferred to return `()` which is different to the `Post` type in the example. In such cases you need to specify the return type explicitly for example via the turbo-fish syntax: `.get_result::<DefTable>(con)`

That written: If you don't plan to use the result of the insert, you can just use `.execute(conn)` which returns the number of modified rows instead.

Comment: ok, thanks! need to get used to this expression stuff...